# PHP: Find a value in an array and return another value once found

Tags: php, arrays, search, echo, key

Totally a PHP noob here so sorry for the possibly basic question - here is what I'm trying achieve. I've got a dynamically generated array that looks something like:

```
$crumbs = 

(

[home] => Array ( 
[label] => Home 
[title] => Go to Home Page 
[first] => 1 
[last] => 
[readonly] => 
) 

[something] => Array ( 
[label] => Shop 
[title] => 
[first] => 
[last] => 1
[readonly] => 
) 

)
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can write something to go through and search (at any depth) to see which array has the key "last" set to a value of 1. When the array with the key is found, I need to then echo out the "label" key for the array which had last = 1. Every array will always have a label key and only one array will ever have the "last" key set to 1. Thanks as always for the help!

Comment: You say `at any depth` but your example shows `last` and `first` always at the same depth. Do you need to search recursively or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($crumbs);

foreach($iterator as $arr) {
  if($arr['last'] == 1) {
    echo $arr['label'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [foreach construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop to go trough the array, or use the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to see if the array contains a value of 1